# iOS: Multiple selectors for toolbar button based on view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view just like the calendar with a day view and list view and month view. These are in a segmented control in the toolbar. When you change the segmented control the middle view is replaced and the navbar and toolbar remain. I have another button called 'Today'. When this is pressed I want it to trigger the selectors in the class that is currently in view. IE: if dayview is loaded it will run the selector in the DayViewController. Is there a way to have multiple selectors depending on what view is currently being shown?

My structure is like so.

### RootViewController

- Toolbar and Navigation bar created
- If Day is selected in the tool bar then DayViewController view is loaded into the middle
- If List is selected in the toolbar then ListViewController view is loaded into the middle

### DayViewController

- (selector) Scroll to today in day view is today is not the current date in view.

### ListViewController

- (selector) Scroll to current section with today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your button point to a generic method like `- (void)todayButtonTapped` then decide what to do:

```
- (void)todayButtonTapped;
{
   if (<check if day is presented>) {
       [self.dayViewController ....
   } else if (<check if week is presented>) {
       [self.weekViewController ...
   } else {
       [self.monthViewController ...
   }
}
```

---

## Update

To make this work in your `rootViewController` add a new property called something like `currentController`. Now every time you change which controller is being shown you update this property to point to that controller. Now all you have to do is make sure your controllers all respond to a similar method and call it

```
[self.currentController todayTapped:sender];
```

Comment: Ok, so have the method in my RootViewController and depending on the view have it call the appropriate method in the class?

Comment: I'm assuming the toolbar is added in the rootViewController so that can response, the rootViewController should also know what controller is loaded and be able to forward the message appropriately. Your structure does seem a little odd will a tabbarcontroller not fit your needs?

Comment: I don't have a `.loaded` in my views.

Comment: You would have to write some kind of logic to know which view is loaded

Comment: Well that is part of the question. Can you expand your post to include this?

Comment: Surely you are presenting the controllers so you must be able to add some method of keeping track of the view you are currently presenting

Comment: I'm detecting if the view is loaded but keep getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error for either the dayview controller or list controller i'm calling it like `[dayView todayPressed]`